# No family member that can pass away

Tags: village

Yesterday we played village when an uncommon situation occurred which I couldn't find a description for in the manual.

I had only one family member alive which was on the farmyard. All the other family members of mine did already pass away or where not born yet or where in the black cloth bag. Then I sent the remaining family member into church so that he was in the black bag too.

When it was my turn again to take a new cube I took a black one which made my marker pass the bridge and usually one of my family members has to die now. But I had none visible in the game who could have died.

In the manual they say:

> A dying family member must be **visible** at the time of his death. This means that he must be either on the game board or on your farmyard (Family members still in the black bag cannot die, nor can ones that have not yet entered play.)

Since I had no family member matching these requirements my question is: What do I do in this particular situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing happens.

The rules do not directly give an answer to this outright; but they are clear that a family member that is not visible; or has not been born yet; cannot die. So you simply cannot kill any village member. The game asks you to do something impossible; so you don’t do it. It is a common rule in other board games in general that you “only do as much as possible”.

There are a couple threads on BGG that agree with this interpretation.

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1323745/passing-away-nobody-visible

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/761561/about-family-member-pass-away